# Не работает авторизация игровых сервисов Google Play

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, google-play, google-play-services

**Unity 2019.4.14f1**
Использую **Bolt** (в приоритете) а также **C#**.
Импортировал скачанный пакет google play сервисов в проект игры.
С помощью гайдов создал скрипт.
По неясным для меня причинам, не работает авторизация игровых сервисов Google Play.
На андроиде никаких окон авторизации не появляется. В консоле Юнити - "Login failed".
В чём проблема?
Код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GpgsScript : MonoBehaviour {

   public string leaderboard;

   void Start()
   {
       PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
       PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
       LogIn();
   }

   public void LogIn()
   {
       Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
       {
           if (success)
           {
               Debug.Log("Login success");
           }
           else
           {
               Debug.Log("Login failed");
           }
       });
   }
   public void OnShowLeaderboard()
   {
       PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowLeaderboardUI(leaderboard);
       Debug.Log("Leaderboard show success");
   }

   public void addScoreLeaderboard(int NewMaxScore)
   {
       Debug.Log("Score report started");
       if (Social.localUser.authenticated)
       {
           Social.ReportScore(NewMaxScore, leaderboard, (bool success) =>
           {
               if (success)
               {
                   Debug.Log("Score report success");
               }
               else
               {
                   Debug.Log("Score report failed");
               }
           });
       }
       else
       {
           Debug.Log("Score report failed - user not authenticated");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Вставьте код текстом.

Comment: Добавил в описание.

Comment: Скриншот можно убрать, он затрудняет чтение вопроса.

Comment: Скриншот - убрал.

Comment: Скорее всего проблема с настройками в Play Console

Comment: У меня лично перед PlayGamesPlatform.Activate стоит ещё 2 строки: ```PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().EnableSavedGames.Build(); и следующая PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);```